# MATLAB Index for not performing a task

Tags: matlab, indexing

Is there a special index in MATLAB, which when used does not induce an operation being performed?

In other words, can I shorten the following code by replacing the `if` clause with something smarter? My goal is to perform some operation on given indices in case they are "sensible", and do nothing in case a special index (such as `-1`, but there might be other better choices) is given.

```
x = magic(3);
r = [ 1, 3 ]; % Do nothing: -1
if ~isequal( r, -1 )
    x( r, : ) = 0;
end
```

Comment: Do you want to check if `r(i)~=-1`? because right now you simply check that `r` is not the scalar `-1`. Anyway, did you try this: `x(r(r>0 & fix(r)==r),:) = 0;`?

Comment: @EBH `-1` was just an example, I thought that maybe you could use something like `NaN`, `inf` or `~`, all of which do not work, I should have been clearer. In any case, my ideal solution is to just use an empty array, `r=[];`, which was too obvious for me to see at first. Thank you for the inspiration, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only option for `r` is either a vector of indices or a scalar that represents "no index", then an [empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530254/2627163) is the best solution.

However, if `r` is always an array (even if in size 1), and you just want to skip the 'non-index' values within it, you can type:

```
x(r(r>0 & fix(r)==r),:)
```

The first part `r>0` takes only positive values from `r`. The second part `fix(r)==r` takes only integer values from `r`. And so you get a subset of `r` with only the values that can be indices `r(r>0 & fix(r)==r)` to use as the row indices for `x`.

Here is an example:

```
r = [5 -1 0 0.3 nan 65 pi];

>> r(r>0 & fix(r)==r)
ans =
     5    65
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do

```
x(r(r~=-1),:) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524148/matlab-index-for-not-performing-a-task#comment78012344_45524148) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45526256/8288778), simply use an empty array as a special index indicating that an operation should not be performed:

```
x = magic(3);
r = []; % [] % 1 % [ 1, 3 ]
x( r, : ) = 0
```

Comment: So all you want is that Matlab won't throw an error if `r` (as a whole) is an illegal index? What if `r = [5 -1 2 0.3 nan]`?

Comment: @EBH No, an operation should not be performed, if `r` as a whole is some special entity, e.g. in this case an empty array. Otherwise, r is guaranteed to contain only valid indices.